# Select TOP 2 highest sum based on two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with the following structure:

```
|     START_DATE        |         END_DATE     | MINUTES | MACHINE |  TYPE  |
23/06/2023 10:05:35      23/06/2023 10:09:35       4         Z       GREEN
23/06/2023 10:10:40      23/06/2023 10:25:40       15        Z       GREEN
23/06/2023 10:25:47      23/06/2023 10:27:47       2         Z       GREEN
23/06/2023 10:27:35      23/06/2023 10:37:35       10        Z       RED
23/06/2023 10:37:35      23/06/2023 10:39:35       2         Z       RED
23/06/2023 10:39:35      23/06/2023 10:45:35       6         X       BLUE
23/06/2023 11:00:00      23/06/2023 11:05:00       5         Y       GREEN
23/06/2023 11:05:00      23/06/2023 11:13:00       8         Y       BLUE
```

I want to create a query that only shows the Top 2 biggest sum of MINUTES for each MACHINE and TYPE in the same date and hour (from START_DATE column), and also show a column where it would concatenate the TYPE with the sum of the minutes. This would be the expected result:

```
|     DATE_HOUR       |   MINUTES | MACHINE |  TYPE_MINUTES  |
    23/06/2023_10           21         Z       GREEN (21 minutes)
    23/06/2023 10           12         Z       RED (12 minutes)
    23/06/2023 11           5          Y       GREEN (5 minutes)
    23/06/2023 11           8          Y       BLUE (8 minutes)
```

Comment: What if there's a 3-way tie?

Comment: If you want the "Top 2 biggest sum of MINUTES for each MACHINE and TYPE" then why is machine `X` not in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select x.*, row_number() over(partition by machine order by m desc) as rn
  from (
    select machine, type, sum(minutes) as m,
      to_char(min(start_date), 'MM/DD/YYYY_HH24') as date_hour
    from t
    group by machine, type
  ) x
) s
where rn <= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

For each `machine` and `type` and date/hour combination, you can `SUM` the `minutes` and then use the `RANK` analytic function to find the greatest two ranked rows for each partition:

```sql
SELECT machine,
       start_date,
       type || ' (' || minutes || ')' AS type_minutes
FROM   (
  SELECT machine,
         type,
         TRUNC(start_date, 'HH24') AS start_date,
         SUM(minutes) AS minutes,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY machine, type ORDER BY SUM(minutes) DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY
         machine,
         type,
         TRUNC(start_date, 'HH24')
)
WHERE  rnk <= 2;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (START_DATE, END_DATE, MINUTES, MACHINE, TYPE ) AS
SELECT DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '10:05:35' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '10:09:35' HOUR TO SECOND,  4, 'Z', 'GREEN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '10:10:40' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '10:25:40' HOUR TO SECOND, 15, 'Z', 'GREEN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '10:25:47' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '10:27:47' HOUR TO SECOND,  2, 'Z', 'GREEN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '10:27:35' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '10:37:35' HOUR TO SECOND, 10, 'Z', 'RED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '10:37:35' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '10:39:35' HOUR TO SECOND,  2, 'Z', 'RED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '10:39:35' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '10:45:35' HOUR TO SECOND,  6, 'X', 'BLUE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '11:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '11:05:00' HOUR TO SECOND,  5, 'Y', 'GREEN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '11:05:00' HOUR TO SECOND, DATE '2023-06-23' + INTERVAL '11:13:00' HOUR TO SECOND,  8, 'Y', 'BLUE' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| MACHINE | START_DATE | TYPE_MINUTES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2023-06-23 10:00:00 | BLUE (6) |
| Y | 2023-06-23 11:00:00 | BLUE (8) |
| Y | 2023-06-23 11:00:00 | GREEN (5) |
| Z | 2023-06-23 10:00:00 | GREEN (21) |
| Z | 2023-06-23 10:00:00 | RED (12) |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UbX-82KH)